# Docker build hangs

Tags: python, docker, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to build a Docker Img for a python program(It's a telegram Bot from [FreeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-to-build-your-first-bot-in-telegram-with-python-4c99526765e4/)),
Now the code runs perfectly but when I try to build this Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6
COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirement.txt

ENV PORT 8080

ENV HOST 0.0.0.0

RUN ["python","bot.py"]
```

The system hangs.

```
dishant_sonawane17@cloudshell:~/project (voice-261819)$ docker build -t python-docker-dev .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.608kB
Step 1/7 : FROM python:3.6
 ---> e0373ff33a19
Step 2/7 : COPY . /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6f9396ff2a64
Step 3/7 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1c216f1a529c
Step 4/7 : RUN pip install -r requirement.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 531e40ac101d
Step 5/7 : ENV PORT 8080
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 385b36f30518
Step 6/7 : ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b1ba2f0bf26e
Step 7/7 : RUN ["python","bot.py"]
 ---> Running in 5ceec7069ee9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your `bot.py` will do, but it will run and wait to finish...
It looks like you want `bot.py` to be the application to start once the container is started.

You should use [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) or [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) for this.

In a nutshell:

> - `RUN` executes command(s) in a new layer and creates a new image. E.g., it is often used for installing software packages.
> - `CMD` sets default command and/or parameters, which can be overwritten from command line when docker container runs.
> - `ENTRYPOINT` configures a container that will run as an executable.

More detailed explanation/source: https://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/.

Comment: This . And the default [`CMD`](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/8341311c62812118a7e2046bbad66da21243f137/3.6/buster/Dockerfile#L132) for this image is `python3` which should explain why it 'hangs'.

Comment: This note from the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) is also relevant: "Do not confuse `RUN` with `CMD`. `RUN` actually runs a command and commits the result; `CMD` does not execute anything at build time, but specifies the intended command for the image."